# Column 'Name' as X-axis label

Tags: excel

This should be ridiculously simple, except I can't seem to find a way to do this!

I want my line/scatter chart to have the actual column 'name' (eg. A, B, C, AA, AB etc.) as their X-axis label. Instead, Excel insists on using the column 'numbers' (1,2,3 etc.)  as the label.

How do I make Excel use the actual column name(s) as the X-axis labels?

**Edit:** 
And I mean the actual Excel-internal column 'name', **not** something that I add as a row and then use as 'labels' !!

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Any pictures of your table and chart?

Comment: Here, [example chart](http://imgur.com/M91KXiF).

Comment: Ah, I see now. I can't think of anything unfortunately. Might be something doable with VBScript though, if someone around knows how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think excel explicitly stores the columns headers as letters which means there would be no way to get them to show in a chart.

You can do it manually in a formula within the chart.

Under Select Data goto Horizontal Axis Labels>edit and put in a formula with your letters

```
={"A","B","C"}
```

Or create a separate row of the column letters to use (which I know you said you didn't want to do).

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),1,"")
```

Gordon

Comment: Both solutions kinda work, but do not answer my original question (as you noted). Doing either of those things feels like a workaround to something that Excel knows of (well, it shows the column letters, right?) but will not let the user make use of!

Comment: I agree and the address function will return the letters but only as a complete string $A$1 after that you need to actually parse the string to get the letter out.  There is no way to get the A out directly.